# "ComponentDidMount" hook triggers memory-leaks if i'm requesting data from the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm slowly trying to remove "Redux" from my workflow, lets say part of components receives required data from the server, when they are be rendered on the screen (in ComponentDidMounth hook), rendering of that components controlled by html5 history router,so if the user starts jumping quickly between routes, in the console comes memory lick warning

can you please tell me some smart way how to fix it. thanks ))

also please show examples with latest react api (HOOKS)

```
const Posts = () => {


    const [posts,setPosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getPosts()
            .then(posts => setPosts(posts))
    },[])


    return (
        <div>
            {/* rendering of posts */}
        </div>
    )
}


const Personal = () => {


    const [profileInfo,setProfileInfo] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        getProfileInfo()
            .then(profileInfo => setProfileInfo(profileInfo))
    },[])


    return (
        <div>
            {/* rendering of personal info.... */}
        </div>
    )
}

const Content = () => {

    return (
        <div className="Content">
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/posts" component={Posts} />
                <Route path="/personal" component={Personal} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
}
```

another Component called sidebar controlls navigation between this components

Comment: This error often happens when you make an asynchronous request for data, but the component unmounts. In `componentWillUnmount` you should remove any timers or listeners created in lifespan of the component and abort async requests. In order to be able to help, please provide your code so we can understand what happens there.

Comment: In my case these async calls triggers memory licks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens when you component is unmounted and you are trying to set the state. A simple way is to modify your `useEffect` to the following code to get rid of this error:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    getPosts().then(posts => {
      if(mounted) setPosts(posts)
    )

    return () => { mounted = false };
},[])
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my be there are another way without that variable?

Comment: This is the simplest way to do. The other thing i know is to have an observer for that. But that will be overrated to use in this simple scenario.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a couple of ways you could use for your situation and i have listed them starting with the simplest option.

1. The first option allows the browser to complete the request but only updates the state with response from the latest request;

```js
useEffect(() => {
        let cancelled = false;

        function fetchData() {
            fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
               .then(result => {
                  if(!cancelled){
                    setData(result)    
                }
            });
        }

        fetchData();

        return () => {
            cancelled = true;
        };

    }, [your deps])
```

2. **Ignoring responses from former api calls**
   You might also want to ignore responses from former api calls.

```js
// A ref to store the last issued pending request
const lastPromise = useRef();

useEffect(() => {


   function fetchData(){
      const currentPromise = fetch(url)
        .then(response => response);

       // store the promise to the ref
       lastPromise.current = currentPromise;

       // handle the result with filtering
       currentPromise.then(result => {
           if (currentPromise === lastPromise.current) {
            setData(result);
           }
       });
   }

  // fire the api request
  fetchData();

}, [your deps]);
```

3. **Cancelling and ignoring**
   Sometimes it is better to cancel former api requests in-flight: the browser can avoid parsing the response and prevent some useless CPU/Network usage. fetch and axios support cancellation using `AbortSignal`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Create the current request's abort controller
  const abortController = new AbortController();

  function fetchData(){
   fetch(url, { signal: abortController.signal })
    .then(data => data)
    // Set the result, if not aborted
    .then(
      result => {
        // IMPORTANT: we still need to filter the results here,
        // in case abortion happens during the delay.
        // In real apps, abortion could happen when you are parsing the json,
        // with code like "fetch().then(res => res.json())"
        // but also any other async then() you execute after the fetch
        if (abortController.signal.aborted) {
          return;
        }
        setState(newState);
      },
    );
  }

  fetchData();

  // Trigger the abortion in useEffect's cleanup function
  return () => {
    abortController.abort();
  };
}, [your deps]);
```

So you can just chose what suits your use case. Hope that helped.